# Map.emplace with multiples arguments C++ 17

Tags: c++, dictionary

Using C++ 17: Having

```
using working_t = bool;
std::map<std::thread, working_t> _pool;
```

I'm trying to add a new thread to this map but I dont find the decent syntax..

```
class ThreadPool {
   std::map<std::thread, working_t> _pool;

   void init() {
      _pool.emplace(&ThreadPool::thread_init, this, false);
   }
   void thread_init();
};
```

This should add a thread to the map with false as value, but it cant compile.. Is this possible?

Comment: You are getting a particular compiler error?  Probably about copying a `std::thread`?

Comment: I'm using emplace for avoid copies. Emplace should create the types with the given arguments

Comment: Do you need the equals sign between `init()` and `{` ?

Comment: miss type, fixed

Comment: What's your use case for looking up a thread in a map? You can never have another instance of that thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need:

```
_pool.emplace(
    std::piecewise_construct,
    std::forward_as_tuple(&ThreadPool::thread_init, this),
    std::forward_as_tuple(false)
);
```

... to distinguish the arguments lists for the key and the value. You will then, however, run into the issue that `std::thread` has no `operator <`, but that's for another question :)

Comment: why is the < operator needed while emplacing?

Comment: @MrSmith it's needed more or less at all times, since `std::map` is an ordered container. I expect issues with the constness of the key as well (is a `const std::thread` usable at all?), so maybe a map is not the right container here.

Comment: @MrSmith because keys in `std::map` are sorted

Comment: @MrSmith its not particular about emplacing, but maps are sorted containers, hence the keys need to have a `<`

Comment: I see.. I wanted to store the thread state, so I will create a map with the thread id and its state..

Comment: @MrSmith may I suggest two `std::vector<std::thread>`s, one for active threads and one for inactive ones?

Comment: @QUentin idk.. it may cost at runtime

Comment: @MrSmith `std::thread` doesn't have `std::hash` nor `operator ==`, so no `std::unordered_map` either (unless, of course, you implement your own comparator & hasher). I don't think the two-vectors solution would have any measurable performance impact.

Comment: @MrSmith If you just want to just store the thread state, having a map of thread id to state does indeed sound like a good idea. The question still remains though how you will store your threads in your thread pool.